# Listview not working for Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I'm trying to create a listView for lecturers in my faculty. There's something wrong, the app don't work, and the preview shows the default listView.

my xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView">

</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my java code is:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class lectures extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView ListView2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
public static String[] names = {"Dr.Aiad","Mr.Hamed","Mr.Qahtan","Dr.reza","Mr.Osamah",};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ListView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, names);
    ListView2.setAdapter(adapter);

}
}
```

Comment: set the height to match_parent maybe?

Comment: Change this public static String[] names = {"Dr.Aiad","Mr.Hamed","Mr.Qahtan","Dr.reza","Mr.Osamah",}; to public static String[] names = {"Dr.Aiad","Mr.Hamed","Mr.Qahtan","Dr.reza","Mr.Osamah"};

Comment: you are giving extra comma in your array

Comment: and remove public static from array

Comment: share your activity_main.xml

Comment: Now you can see the full xml code

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this :)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

class lectures extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView listView2;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
 String[] names = {"Dr.Aiad","Mr.Hamed","Mr.Qahtan","Dr.reza","Mr.Osamah"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView2 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_list_item, names);
    listView2.setAdapter(adapter);

 }
}
```

Hope it helps you!! :)

Comment: When I delete "android" from "adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, names);" it gives me error (cannot resolve symbol) for activity_list_item.